# PHP variable goes outside HTML link href string?

Tags: php, html, css, sass

So I want one link when I am working locally and one link when I upload the page to my site. So I came up with the genius idea to use a variable for this. So that I don't have to manually change all the links when I upload a new version of the site.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo $link ?>/css/app.css">
```

```
<?php
    $link = $local;

    if ($link == $local) {
        echo 'http://local.site/';
    }

    else if ($link == $online) {
        echo 'http://uploadesite.com/';
    }
?>
```

Yet, the variable goes outside the href, like this:

```
"http://local.site/"
<title>Etc | Om Mig</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/app.css">
```

I've tried quite a few things but I couldn't find anything that worked without you changing the string content itself (css/app.css in this example) to include it in the echo.

Comment: _Of course_ this doesn’t work … you are outputting $link unchanged - and then the base address _somewhere else_. If you want to be able to still use just `<?php echo $link ?>` in that place - then you should change what the variable $link contains accordingly, _before_ any such lines.

Comment: `$link = $local;  if ($link == $local) {` Is it me or wont this ALWAYS be true cause you just MADE IT TRUE

Comment: I think you use php under html code, so it's preferable to change `echo` with `$link =` and don't close the php file `?>`

Comment: You're echoing the link in place instead of assigning to to a variable for use later.

Comment: If you change `href="css/app.css"` then you can forget about all this completely

Comment: 04FS, if I understand correctly you mean the php code with the if and else statement should be above the html? And/or that the $link = $local; should be under the if else statement? I tried those things, it doesn't work still

Comment: remove `/` in end of the `echo`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your $local variable into string. Also, put these lines on top. So, it echoes properly in the css link.

```
$link = "local";

if ($link == "local") {
    $link =  'http://local.site/';
}
else if ($link == "online") {
    $link =  'http://uploadesite.com/';
}
```